# How we can Upload files into rackspace cloud container with API in C#

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest, rackspace-cloud

I want to Upload files into rackspace cloud container with API in C# and I am using .net 4.0 version. So, how I can create webrequest for this. Even I successfully created containers with the same request but I am not able to create object into my container.

Number of times I tried to upload my file into my container but I am continuously getting error like Unauthorized access and my code is shown below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(authInfo.StorageUrl + "/TestContainer/myfile.txt")) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "PUT";
request.Headers["X-Auth-Token"] = MyToken;
byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\myfile.txt");
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
//request.Headers["Content-Length"] = "512000";
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong with this.

Comment: Please share your answer / solution with the Community.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't written the bytes to the request stream.  Do something like this:

```
Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();

reqStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

reqStream.Close();

Webresponse response = request.getresponse();
```